# Why does the aligned list of words printed duplicate?

Tags: python, list, alignment, cpu-word, synonym

I'm trying to implement *Sultan Monolingual Aligner* in finding a synsets using `NLTK wordnet synsets`.

And I have two lists :

```
word1 = ['move', 'buy','learn']
word2 = ['study', 'purchase']
```

Based on the aligner rules, if synsets of `word1[i]` of `word1` is similar with synsets of `word2[j]` of `word2`, then `word1[i]` and `word2[j]` will be aligned.

And here's my code :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def getSynonyms(word):
    synonymList1 = []
    wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(word)
    tempList1=[]
    for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
        synLemmas = synset1.lemma_names()
        for i in xrange(len(synLemmas)):
            word = synLemmas[i].replace('_',' ')
            if word not in tempList1:
                tempList1.append(word)
    synonymList1.append(tempList1)
    return synonymList1

def cekSynonyms(word1, word2):
    newlist = []
    for i in xrange(len(word1)):
        for j in xrange(len(word2)):
            getsyn1 = getSynonyms(word1[i])
            getsyn2 = getSynonyms(word2[j])
            ds1 = [x for y in getsyn1 for x in y]
            ds2 = [x for y in getsyn2 for x in y]
            print ds1,"---align to--->",ds2,"\n"
            for k in xrange(len(ds1)):
                for l in xrange(len(ds2)):
                    if ds1[k] == ds2[l]:
                        #newsim = [ds1[k], ds2[l]]
                        newsim = [word1[i], word2[j]]
                        newlist.append(newsim)
    return newlist

word1 = ['move', 'buy','learn']
word2 = ['study', 'purchase']
print cekSynonyms(word1, word2)
```

And yes, I could find a synsets of each words. here's the output :

```
[u'move', u'relocation', u'motion', u'movement', u'motility', u'travel', u'go', u'locomote', u'displace', u'proceed', u'be active', u'act', u'affect', u'impress', u'strike', u'motivate', u'actuate', u'propel', u'prompt', u'incite', u'run', u'make a motion'] ---align to---> [u'survey', u'study', u'work', u'report', u'written report', u'discipline', u'subject', u'subject area', u'subject field', u'field', u'field of study', u'bailiwick', u'sketch', u'cogitation', u'analyze', u'analyse', u'examine', u'canvass', u'canvas', u'consider', u'learn', u'read', u'take', u'hit the books', u'meditate', u'contemplate'] 

[u'move', u'relocation', u'motion', u'movement', u'motility', u'travel', u'go', u'locomote', u'displace', u'proceed', u'be active', u'act', u'affect', u'impress', u'strike', u'motivate', u'actuate', u'propel', u'prompt', u'incite', u'run', u'make a motion'] ---align to---> [u'purchase', u'leverage', u'buy'] 

[u'bargain', u'buy', u'steal', u'purchase', u'bribe', u'corrupt', u"grease one's palms"] ---align to---> [u'survey', u'study', u'work', u'report', u'written report', u'discipline', u'subject', u'subject area', u'subject field', u'field', u'field of study', u'bailiwick', u'sketch', u'cogitation', u'analyze', u'analyse', u'examine', u'canvass', u'canvas', u'consider', u'learn', u'read', u'take', u'hit the books', u'meditate', u'contemplate'] 

[u'bargain', u'buy', u'steal', u'purchase', u'bribe', u'corrupt', u"grease one's palms"] ---align to---> [u'purchase', u'leverage', u'buy'] 

[u'learn', u'larn', u'acquire', u'hear', u'get word', u'get wind', u'pick up', u'find out', u'get a line', u'discover', u'see', u'memorize', u'memorise', u'con', u'study', u'read', u'take', u'teach', u'instruct', u'determine', u'check', u'ascertain', u'watch'] ---align to---> [u'survey', u'study', u'work', u'report', u'written report', u'discipline', u'subject', u'subject area', u'subject field', u'field', u'field of study', u'bailiwick', u'sketch', u'cogitation', u'analyze', u'analyse', u'examine', u'canvass', u'canvas', u'consider', u'learn', u'read', u'take', u'hit the books', u'meditate', u'contemplate'] 

[u'learn', u'larn', u'acquire', u'hear', u'get word', u'get wind', u'pick up', u'find out', u'get a line', u'discover', u'see', u'memorize', u'memorise', u'con', u'study', u'read', u'take', u'teach', u'instruct', u'determine', u'check', u'ascertain', u'watch'] ---align to---> [u'purchase', u'leverage', u'buy'] 

[['buy', 'purchase'], ['buy', 'purchase'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study']]
```

the 6 rows above are each words inside both of `word1` and `word2` being compared by their synsets.

the bottom row is the aligned words.

as we can see by the synsets, `['buy','purchase']` and `['learn','study']` are the aligned words.

but why does the output printed more than once? like this >> `[['buy', 'purchase'], ['buy', 'purchase'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study']]`

how to print it only once without repitition? like this >> `[['buy','purchase'], ['learn','study']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicates from such a list by converting it to a set, though because lists are not hashable, you'll have to go through tuples on the way:

```py
a = [['buy', 'purchase'], ['buy', 'purchase'], ['learn', 'study'], \\
     ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study'], ['learn', 'study']]
a = [list(x) for x in set([tuple(x) for x in a])]
print(a)
```

Gives:

```
[['buy', 'purchase'], ['learn', 'study']]
```

Answer (score 0):

based on mr. `nbubis` answer, here I code a tuple function :

```
def tupleSynonyms(word1, word2):
    a = cekSynonyms(word1, word2)
    anew = [list(x) for x in set([tuple(x) for x in a])]
    return anew

print tupleSynonyms(word1, word2)
```